# lingpipe - How to extract tokens and Named-entities into a single list

Tags: java, tokenize, named-entity-recognition

I am working on a project that needs to extract tokens from text. This tokens should also contain named entities.

For example, the text:

```
 50 Cent is almost irrelevant to hiphop
```

my desired output

```
50 Cent
is
almost 
irrelevant
to
hiphop
```

I can do token extraction with LingPipe but I don't know how to use the Exact Dictionary-Based Chunking approach to get my desired output. Ideas/examples on how to go about it would be appreciated.

Comment: [I learned something today](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition)

Comment: @keyser really, what did you learn

Comment: That there's a concept called _Named-entity recognition_. It wasn't me hinting about wikipedia if that's what you thought :p

Comment: I guess I should thank you :p